# How to add two file files with a different x-basis in gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot

If you have two files both structured like this

```
1 1.2
2 1.3
3 1.4
4 1.5
5 1.6
6 1.7
```

you can simply add them by doing

```
p "<paste file1.txt file2.txt" u 1:($2+$4) w l
```

But if the second file is structured with less points, e.g.

```
1 1.2
3 1.4
5 1.6
7 1.8
```

this is no longer an option because both files have a different length. My first option was to just manually cut out the unnecessary points with vim, but since there are hundreds of files I would like to know if there is an easy gnuplot solution.

I want to ignore points which only appear in one of the files. Points which appear in both files should be added.

Following @TomFenech's advice I used `awk` combined with gnuplot's `every` to only plot the odd points

```
plot '<awk ''FNR==NR {a[FNR]=$1; cnt=FNR} {x[$1] += $2} END {for(i=1; i<=cnt; ++i) print a[i],x[a[i]]}'' test1.txt test2.txt' u 1:2 every 2::1 w l
```

[image]

Comment: I think it would be easier to write a simple shell script to cut out the points automatically.

Comment: You need to reshape your files, which is most easily done outside gnuplot, e.g. using `awk`. One important consideration is whether your data is evaluated at fixed x values (as in your example) or different data files might have non-coincident x values, and therefore you would need interpolation of some kind.

Comment: Perhaps if you included enough of a sample from both files to exhibit the zigzagging behaviour, we could try and get to the bottom of it.

Comment: Considering the confusion which arose (judging from the various comments): What do you want to happen for the merge? What should happen for equal x-value, and what to the other x-values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could combine the two files using awk:

```
plot '<awk ''{a[$1]+=$2} END {for (i in a) print i, a[i]}'' file1.txt file2.txt'
```

Using awk is potentially more flexible if you wanted to combine the files in a more complicated way.

Comment: If I try this, I get the same zig-zag object as with using the `smooth frequency` option, however, I changed the awk statement a bit, and combined it with `every` to print only the odd lines like this
    'plot '<awk ''FNR==NR {a[FNR]=$1; cnt=FNR} {x[$1] += $2} END {for(i=1; i<=cnt; ++i) print a[i],x[a[i]]}'' test1.txt test2.txt' u 1:2 every 2::1 w l'
and now I obtain what I wanted

Comment: @user3165456 glad you got it working. I'm guessing that the x values don't match up perfectly in your data, otherwise I don't see why you'd be having any problem with either of these two approaches. Perhaps you need to do some rounding or interpolation to make the values match.

Answer (score 2):

You could use `smooth frequency` option to plot sum of values with same `x`

```
     plot '<cat file1.txt file2.txt' using 1:2 smooth frequency
```

**Edit:**

cumulative --> frequency

Comment: You mean `smooth frequency`. Yes, that looks like a good idea!

Comment: If I try this, I get a zig-zag object. And combining it with every to plot only the odd points gives strange results

Comment: @user3165456 You haven't been clear about what should happen for two points with equal x-value. With `smooth frequency` the points with the same x-value are added up. If you want the average value you should use `smooth unique`.

Comment: If I want two points with the same x value, I want to add them, if the point only appears in one of the files I want to ignore it. You're right, this was not at all clear in my original question!

Comment: Ok, then I guess you cannot use any smoothing function ;)